# unable to round-trip http request to upstream

Tags: asp.net-core, postman

What did mean this error...? I have a simple .Net Core API project.When I run that and send request to it by my **local Postman**,every thing is true and I get response from application.But when I try to send a request from **remote Postman** to that,I get above error..!! Connection between PCs is established because sending a request to other my project from remote Postman is return response.It seams there are a problem in my project or must be to add some changes in my project,but I don't now what's that.Please help me..

Comment: Careful not to use any VPN or proxy while loading your site.

Answer (score 0):

I change my project from https to http in project properties(Debug tab) and so in Program.cs change UseUrls method on webBuilder to http url.